# Need help with a math proof

Tags: proof-writing

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $m,n,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $0 < m < n$ and $0 < p < q$ then $mp < nq$.

Comment: @Ishfaaq m>n means m-n$\in$ $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: see this:  $mp<np\leq nq$

Answer (score 1):

Given: $0 < m < n$

Multiply both sides by positive number p

=>$0 < mp < np$

Given: $0 < p < q$ so clear:

=>$0 < mp < np < nq$

=> $mp < nq$ as required.

QED

Answer (score 1):

$$  nq - mp = nq -np +np - mp = n(q-p) + (n-m)p  $$
OR
$$  nq - mp = nq -mq +mq - mp = (n-m)q + m(q-p)  $$

Comment: How did you get nq-mq + mq-mp?

Comment: @user3182252 My favorite high school teacher called it a Propitious Zero. Add and subtract the same thing. Sometimes it helps.

Comment: My professor has not taught or mentioned that, so I don't believe I can use that for this proof.

Comment: @user3182252, when you get the chance, ask your professor or TA about the idea.